# Long frame times are an indication of jank

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll, developer-tools, web-animations

[image]Google and their developers say you should test for performance and get as close to 60fps, but the tool seems to be broken or they do a shitty job at this too:

- Visit `google.com` and search for something
- Open chrome developer tools,
- Go to timeline -> press record (Black dot in the left side)
- Scroll in the results page
- Stop the recording
- Be surprised

Even if this is a page without any fancy animations or heavy JS, the timeline is red and it says:

> Long frame times are an indication of jank.

Why is this. Is google having some front-end issues, or the recording tool is broken?